# Video synchronization: Sound is faster than video - how to fix this?

Tags: windows, video, sync

I have a large video file (.avi), and as it is playing, the picture is becoming more and more late from the sound.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the video in Sony Vegas, unlock the audio from video, split the audio in 3 or more parts, move the parts so that they fill the whole timeline, with minimal distances between each other. Audio will just disappear sometimes, but it will be somewhat synchronized